# Getting user/email from ionic io Social Providers?

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, google-plus

I'm building an app with ionic 1.3 and ionic io as a auth backend.

The app logs into both Facebook and Google+ as per the documentation, but only stores the user token.

Calling Ionic.User.current() in the app also only returns the same id and a 'name' variable as null.

How do we get access to the the data? Feels wrong having to ask the user to provide it after they wanted to use the connivance of a Social provided login option.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve